why is my code outputting "audio_features is empty. Skipping LSTM preparation."
I'm trying to import a librispeech dataset into my code and then train using it but I keep getting:

audio_features is empty. Skipping LSTM preparation.

The librispeech folders include .txt at the top and .flac files underneath the .txt files.
import librosa
import os
import numpy as np

def load_librispeech_dataset(directory):
  audio_files = []
  labels = []
  for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
      if file.endswith('.flac'):
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        try:
          audio, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)
          mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40)
          audio_files.append(np.mean(mfccs.T, axis=0))

          # Assuming the label (transcription) is in a corresponding text file
          label_path = file_path.replace('.flac', '.txt')
          with open(label_path, 'r') as label_file:
            label = label_file.read().strip()
            labels.append(label)
        except Exception as e:
          print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")
  
  return np.array(audio_files), labels # Indentation corrected: Return after processing all files

dataset_directory = 'C:\\Users\\rowro\\Downloads\\train-clean-100\\LibriSpeech\\train-clean-100'
audio_features, transcriptions = load_librispeech_dataset(dataset_directory)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical  # Import to_categorical

if audio_features.size == 0:
    print("audio_features is empty. Skipping LSTM preparation.")
else:

    audio_features = audio_features.reshape(audio_features.shape[0], 1, audio_features.shape[1])  # Reshape for LSTM

    
    vocabulary = sorted(list(set(transcriptions)))
    
    transcription_to_index = {transcription: index for index, transcription in enumerate(vocabulary)}
   
    indexed_transcriptions = [transcription_to_index[transcription] for transcription in transcriptions]
   
    one_hot_transcriptions = to_categorical(indexed_transcriptions, num_classes=len(vocabulary))
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((audio_features, one_hot_transcriptions))

epochs = 50


I can only assume that when you called load_librispeech_dataset(dataset_directory), nothing got loaded.  The usual troubleshooting steps would seem to apply.
